# Conditional statement on all objects of a struct without writing every single one?

Tags: c++, object, struct, conditional-statements, esp32

I am working on a smart gardening app that will run off an ESP32 and was wondering how to apply a conditional statement on a specific variable of each object without referencing each object specifically. I made a struct that defines devices directly connected to the ESP32. Here's a small snippet:

```cpp
    struct device
    {
    public:
        int pin;
        bool pwrStatus = false;
        int hours;
        int minutes;
        int duration; 
        int iterations; 
     };
```

My goal is to compare the variables stored in hours and minutes in each object against the current hours and minutes retrieved from an NTP server **without** writing every individual device's name like such:

```cpp
    if((fan.hours==ntpHours) && (fan.minutes==ntpMinutes)){
        // *do something*
    }
    else if((ac.hours==ntpHours) && (ac.minutes==ntpMinutes)){
        // *do something*
    }
```

Although I know it's not possible, I would like to write something similar to this:

```cpp
    if((device.hours==ntpHours) && (device.minutes==ntpMinutes)){
        // *do something*
    }
```

Comment: Hint: a method of this class can refer to its members as "hours", "minutes", etc...

Comment: Considering both structures are POD type (just basic primitive types), you could use `memcmp`. Implementing `operator==` could do, too.

Comment: The question isn't very clear (as you can see from above comments) but my take on this is that you need to be all your device objects into a vector. Then you can write a loop to compare all objects in the vector and take appropriate action.

Comment: @AlexG -- there can be padding between struct members, and that padding is not required to have the same contents for each object. So `memcmp` won't necessarily work.

Comment: You can for sure write operators that you can use to compare a `device` with a `ntp` object, but we don't have much to go on. Do you have a `std::vector<device>`? Each `device` has a timestamp that is comparable with an `ntp` object? What does the `ntp` object look like?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Currently I do not have an `ntp` object, I simply retrieved the hours and minutes and stored them as `int ntpHours, ntpMinutes;`. However, I did not think of creating a struct to compare these variables.

Comment: @Jeebus Ok, then create a `struct timestamp { int h, m; }` that you use for both `ntp` and then you add one `timestamp` member to `device`. You can then go nuts overloading `operator<`, `operator==` etc for this `timestamp`. Comparisons should be easy later.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I don't think you're addressing their actual problem. It's not about comparing multiple members, it's comparing all the different devices.

Comment: @Barmar Ok, I got stuck on "_My goal is to compare the variables stored in hours and minutes in each object against the current hours and minutes retrieved from an NTP server_"

Answer (score 0):

Put pointers to all your devices in a vector, then you can loop over them.

```
std::vector<device*> all_devices {&fan, &ac, ...};
...

for (auto &dev : all_devices) {
    if (dev->hours == ntpHours && dev->minutes == ntpMinutes) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: When you write `all_devices.push_back(&fan);` wouldn't this still require me to name every device in order to add it to the vector?

Comment: Yes, but you only have to do it once, not all the places that need to operate on all devices.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ESP32. Perhaps it already has a built-in array of all devices, in which case you could use that instead of creating your own vector. But something has to give a name to the collection.

Comment: I'm not sure why want to use `std::vector<device*>`? Why not just `std::vector<device>`?

Comment: That would make copies in the vector, instead of referring to the device structures that are actually used to interface with the hardware devices.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the C++20 has an answer for the special case of comparison:

```
struct device{
    auto operator<=>( device const & ) const= default;//abracadabra
    ...
};
```

And all comparison operators or lexicographically defined automatically - provided that the counterparts exist for all members.
But make sure to compile against C++20. Otherwise there's no luck.

cheers,
FM.